# link onclick pass object

Tags: javascript, href

What i'm trying to do, is pass the object of the link to my javascript function for an ajax query so I can add a loading image next to the link while it's loading.

I thought of wrapping a div around it with the event.

Is this compliant, and will work with all browsers? It seems to work in the one's I have tested, but I only have the newer versions.

```
<html>
<script>
    blah = function(obj){
        alert(obj);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<body>

<div onclick="return blah(this);"><a href="http://www.google.com/">work!</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need to be sure of, will doing the return false; on the parent div of the link make sure that when the link is clicked it will not go to the url?

It doesn't seem possible to pass the object of an actual href=. Maybe i'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. Currently you are not passing the  element to your function, but your div.

You can try this:

```
<html>
<script>
    blah = function(objId){ 
       var linkElement = document.getElementById(objId);
       var fakeHref = linkElement.getAttribute('fakehref');
       alert(fakeHref);
    }
</script>
<body>

<a id="link" href="javascript:blah('link');" fakehref="http://www.google.com/">work!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Click here to see a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wYu5M/